# what is the problem with my code, it is not returning value if b!=-1

Tags: c, function, return

what is the problem with my code, it is not returning value if b!=-1

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int find_even(int k){
    int a,b,i=0;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    while (a>=0){
        if(i<k){
            if (a>=0 && a%2 == 0){
                b=a;
                i++;
            }

        }
        scanf("%d",&a);
    }
    if (i<k){
        b=-1;
    }
    return b;

}

void main(){
    int k;
    printf("Enter the value of K : ");
    scanf("%d",&k);
    printf("Enter the sequence of non negative integers and at end enter a negative integer  : ");
    if (find_even(k)<0)
        printf("No %dth even integer exist.",k);
    else
        printf("Result = %d. ",find_even(k));
}
```

I am trying to get the kth even digit but I am not getting any value returned whenever the value of b isn't equal to -1

Comment: if the first call to `find_even()` doesn't return -1, you call `find_even()` again as a parameter to `printf()` so it will `scanf()`for another user input. I don't think that's what you want

Comment: What happens if the user enters -1 at each prompt?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you do not seem to get output unless you enter -1 is because you must enter at least `k` even numbers for `(i<k)` to be true.  Each time you enter a positive even number in the loop, i increments:

```
if (a>=0 && a%2 == 0){
    b=a;
    i++;  // here
```

So if you enter a positive even number (say 2) more than k times, you will get a result that isn't -1.

After you return from the function, if the result is negative, you do:

```
printf("No %dth even integer exist.",k);
```

If the result is positive, you go back into the function for a second time:

```
printf("Result = %d. ",find_even(k)); // This is going to re-enter find_even
```

I think what you want to here is save the result of the function call and act on that.  Like this:

```
int result = find_even(k);
if (result<0)
    printf("No %dth even integer exist.",k);
else
    printf("Result = %d. ", result);
```

Edit:  I think I understand what you are trying to do now.  It was a bit confusing given the request and the way things line up on the screen. Add a `\n` to the end of the `printf` to make this less confusing on the terminal:

```
printf("Enter the sequence of non negative integers and at end enter a negative integer  :\n");
```

Now, all the input will be aligned and make more sense.

Also, be careful with `scanf()` as it is not the most reliable function.  It is good for tinkering, but it is unsafe for general purpose use.  Check out [this](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html) little guide for more info on `scanf` and all of its intricacies to using it correctly.